# How to Archive Files in SSIS even if the tasks inside the Sequence containers fails

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

In one of my SSIS package, I have three different Sequence containers in which the tasks inside the containers will load the excel files to SQL db. Till here the package working fine. But i need to archive those processed files. To achieve this i configured the FileSystem  task. Here, when i am trying to place this FileSystem task common to all these containers, the package keeps failing. But when i configured three different FileSystem Tasks for all the three containers, the archiving process working fine.

**Q1. How to configure the FileSystem task common for all the containers.**

**Q2. How can i configure the Sequence Container, if any of the task inside the Sequence Container fails, My FileSystem task should work**
[image: Here is the Sample Package that i created]

Comment: At the same time if any of the task inside the Sequence container fails, i just want to move the file to the other folder. to achieve this how can my package detects if any of the task failed inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

Double click the green arrow coming from the sequence container and set the condition for advancement to continue allways.

Comment: @Willemse, I want to perform different tasks based on the conditions,
1. If any of the task inside Sequence container fails--> Run Task 'A'
2. If none of the task inside Sequence container failed--> Run Task 'B'
So, how can i capture these two conditions...to let the tasks A or B to run

Answer (score 0):

Edit the Precendence Constraints (green arrows) going to your System Task "Archive File" and change the value in the Constraint Options from Success to Completion... then the arrow should turn blue.